# LWJGL 3: GLFW: Fullscreen error, only partial cover?

Tags: java, windows, lwjgl, game-engine, glfw

This is a bizarre issue. I have a 4k monitor, and when rendering a fullscreen window with a resolution that is 4k, everything works fine. If that resolution is any smaller, however, it only covers up part of the screen, exposing the rest of the desktop underneath, like this:

[image: Partial Fullscreen]

The actual resolution switches successfully; the image above is a 1080p screenshot on a 4k monitor, but the "display area" is still undersized. I'm almost positive this is a symptom of the scaling in Windows 10, but I can't even find a scaling setting that fits, default is 300%, shown above, and 100% just makes the area smaller. I also don't have a clue about how to handle it if this was the case.

I'm pretty sure there's just something obvious that I'm not aware of, it's been difficult to find any related issues, and the closest I've come was a GLFW bug reported 2 years ago that isn't even relevant anymore.

EDIT:

I modified the LWJGL example at their website to demonstrate this issue:

```
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.system.*;

import java.nio.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.*;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class Test {

    // The window handle
    private long window;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

        init();
        loop();

        // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if ( !glfwInit() )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        // Configure GLFW
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(1600, 900, "Hello World!", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
        });

        // Get the thread stack and push a new frame
        try ( MemoryStack stack = stackPush() ) {
            IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*
            IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1); // int*

            // Get the window size passed to glfwCreateWindow
            glfwGetWindowSize(window, pWidth, pHeight);

            // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
            GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

            // Center the window
            glfwSetWindowPos(
                    window,
                    (vidmode.width() - pWidth.get(0)) / 2,
                    (vidmode.height() - pHeight.get(0)) / 2
            );
        } // the stack frame is popped automatically

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    private void loop() {
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
        // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
        // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
        // bindings available for use.
        GL.createCapabilities();

        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
        // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
        while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) ) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

            // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
            // invoked during this call.
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().run();
    }

}
```

Notice `window = glfwCreateWindow(1600, 900, "Hello World!", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);`. By specifying a monitor, you are requesting fullscreen mode in GLFW, and it finds the closest compatible resolution to the size arguments given based on hardware i suppose, but my monitor is a 4K monitor, and unless I specify 4096 x 2160, I get the same bizarre result. Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Basically, making a display fullscreen removes the window border.  If you need to make it fullscreen, get the screen size (in pixels) and set the window size to that.  Then if you need to change resolution of image, use a frame buffer.

Comment: So I can't go into fullscreen mode in 1080p, or any other resolution other than my native monitor resolution? I am certainly able to just switch to fullscreen in 4K flawlessly but I want to be able to display in a smaller resolution. Keep in mind, my monitor switches to 1080p input when I go fullscreen at 1920 x 1080, but thats when this error happens.

Comment: Yeah, I used to run into that issue when I used LWJGL.  Just make it fullscreen and use framebuffers to do resolution of screen

Comment: Huh, what version of LWJGL were you using? as of 3.1.2, GLFW allows you to switch to fullscreen by specifying a monitor in 'glfwCreateWindow()' or by setting the monitor via 'glfwSetWindowMonitor()' at runtime without losing the context. It sounds like you're describing the windowed full screen workaround that was necessary prior to the update? http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html

Comment: I was using 3.0.2, so that was before the fix.